# Data table and knockout integration working issue

Tags: knockout.js, datatables

Hi every one i am working on a project where i had to integrate knockout and datatables and i had to achieve CRUD operations using them...
I have used knockout-datatables.js downloaded from this source
https://github.com/CogShift/Knockout.Extensions
my application is working properly but while iam performing rowlevel remove /edit..... which is similar to this
example  acshttp://jsfiddle.net/ducka/haq2y/

the rowlevel event (example remove) will work only once... next if i have to make it work i have to either sort or use pagination i am not understanding why is it happening so ....can some one please help me

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi there.  Its important to know that when posting a question on StackOverflow you'll get much better answers if you can post some code demonstrating the problem.  That said, I have an idea what might be happening...

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with incorrectly re-binding the view once a delete is performed.  If your data or view is re-bound after a delete, make sure you're not over-writing your original observables with new ones.  For example, if your model has a property defined as :

```
self.myData = ko.observableArray([initialData]);
```

and you get new data from AJAX, **make sure you aren't doing this** :

```
self.myData = ko.observableArray([newData]);
```

and instead **you want to do this** :

```
self.myData([newData]);
```

Without more information in your original post, I'm afraid this is just a guess.

For a more in-depth discussion of this, check out "The Right Way to Reset your View Model" in the blog post here : http://ryanrahlf.com/getting-started-with-knockout-js-3-things-to-know-on-day-one/

Answer (score 0):

use [this custom binding designed for datatables](https://github.com/zachpainter77/DatatablesForEach-Custom-Knockout-Binding)  -->

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach = {
page: 0,
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  ko.unwrap(options.data);
  if(options.dataTableOptions.paging){
    valueAccessor().data.subscribe(function (changes) {
        var table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
        ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page = table.page();
        table.destroy();
    }, null, 'arrayChange');          
  }
    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
        if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);  
        }
    });
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {        
    var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
        key = 'DataTablesForEach_Initialized';
    ko.unwrap(options.data);
    var table;
    if(!options.dataTableOptions.paging){
      table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
        table.destroy();
    }
    ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable(options.dataTableOptions);
    if (options.dataTableOptions.paging) {
       if (table.page.info().pages - ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page == 0) 
           table.page(--ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);                
       else 
           table.page(ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);                
    }        
    if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (options.data || options.length))
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}};
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/5pznw6re/)